# How to remove emoji from string - ios?

Tags: ios, unicode, emoji

I've seen many of the answers are based on the unicode of the character and the unicode of the emodji range, but the emoji is added every year, it is difficult to maintain. Is there a simpler way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there seems to be a very easy solution to this:

```
func removeEmojisFromString(_ string: String) -> String {
    string.unicodeScalars.filter { !($0.properties.isEmoji && $0.properties.isEmojiPresentation) }.map { String($0) }.joined()
}
```

Tested with

```
let filtered = removeEmojisFromString("This is actually pretty easy  iOS has a native categorization for emoji? ")
print(filtered)
```

and the result is `This is actually pretty easy  iOS has a native categorization for emoji?`

There are some extra spaces you might need to remove as well but that is another thing.

Comment: Thanks! But 'isEmoji' is only available in iOS 10.2 or newer. We need to support iOS 10.0 and 10.1.

Comment: @Yvan seems like a rather important peace of information that you might want to put in your question, don't you think? As this is a public post the answer seems acceptable for people stumbling on to this in the future. For your specific case I suggest you create a new question.

Comment: I tested with your method and there's still problem. 
```let filtered = removeEmojisFromString("Hi,1999") 
print(filtered)```
the result is ```Hi,```, "1999" is missing which is wrong.

Comment: @Yvan My apologies. Please check the updated version.